# How do I use the 'animationImages' method with programatically created UIImageViews

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview

I have programatically created 15 or so `UIImageViews` and given them tags.

I have used the [UIView anim...... method to move them about using `[self.view viewWithTag:tag]` to reference them.

However, `[self.view viewWithTag:tag]` does not appear to work with `animationImages`. Xcode states Property `animationImages` not found on object of type 'UIView'.

I am trying to move them and animate them at the same time. I have spent all day scouring the web for the answer but to no avail.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check if `[self.view viewWithTag:tag]` is of type UIImageView and then call the `animationImages` method on that. The warning states that UIView doesn't support `animationImages` since return type of `viewWithTag:` [is a UIView and not UIImageView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/viewWithTag%3a).

You can try something similar to this:

```
UIView *aView = [self.view viewWithTag:tag];

if ([aView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
   UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)aView;
   imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWith....];//some images    
}
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks for your help. Just so I understand the code and not just cut and paste. When we say 'UIView *aView = [self.view viewWithTag:tag];' we are not making a copy of the 'viewWithTag' but *aView is just a pointer to the same object that ['viewWithTag' is pointing at. Therefore when we apply changes to aView, it is in essence updating 'viewWithTag' as they point to the same thing?